Is this question (about blockchain generally) on topic?
I found What can blockchain do that normal databases systems won't?. The text of the question asks about blockchain advantages and real life use cases outside of cryptocurrencies.
I would like the answer this question, but I can't see how to do it and stay on topic. Obviously, the answers wouldn't say anything about bitcoin because bitcoin is entirely designed from the ground up to support a cryptocurrency use case.
If questions about non-bitcoin blockchains are off topic, how is this on topic?
(For the record, I strongly opposed the change in scope for bitcoin.SE precisely because it would make it impossible to have these kinds of discussions.)

Pieter said it well: "sufficiently generic things should probably remain on topic here anyway". Other answers on that discussion appear to also endorse general cryptocurrency/blockchain questions.
From what I understand, the main frustration was with being the kitchen sink for all the hyperspecific, lazily written, or obscure altcoin questions that hardly got any attention by anyone other than the asker, whereas multiple of the bigger other cryptocurrencies got sites delimited to their own coin specifically.
Interesting questions about blockchain fit fine, please answer away.

Then, at a minimum, the site needs a "bitcoin" tag so people can mark questions that aren't about blockchain generally. If such answers are on topic (but completely different from bitcoin-specific answers), questioners need some way to specify what kind of question they're asking.

Given that the majority of this site's content is about Bitcoin, a [tag:bitcoin] tag would not be a useful means to categorize content.

It would if it was used specifically to indicate that a question was intended to be limited to bitcoin (where it's open to a more general interpretation). The alternative would be have a tag like "blockchain" to indicate that the intent was not to get a bitcoin-specific answer. But it's unlikely people would actually use that tag. Ack, I just checked. We have a "blockchain" tag, but IT IS BITCOIN SPECIFIC! Argh.
